# What is the best filesystem for backing up on external hard drive?

Tags: filesystems

I have a 1TB consumer grade NAS and I can use whatever file system I please on it. I only plan to ever use it with linux based systems, so windows compatibility is not really a priority. What is the best file system for archiving? JFS? Ext3? Ext4? btrfs?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ext4 with journaling turned on and delayed allocation (dealloc) turned off.  The extents (introduced in ext4, but also available in xfs) will speed up dealing with large files--which I assume you'll be using.

Comment: Could you expand a bit on why you recommend those exact settings for journaling and delayed allocation?

Comment: @kasperd This is a 6 year old answer, but... the only suggestions I gave were journalling on, delayed allocation off.  Both prevent data loss, and there are a variety of articles about why these settings are valuable.

Comment: This may be a 6 year old answer, but it was edited just a couple of hours before my comment.

Answer (score 1):

Btrfs is quite stable nowadays [well, at least relatively :-) for 2.6.37 kernel] **and** it supports *on-fly compression*, amongst other nice features.

Ext4 is quite nice as well. Unless you're risky enough for Btrfs EXT4 could be good choice, **but** it's also not such matured comparing to EXT3.

JFS as a surprise, supports extents for a long time, formats/mounts fast and hence can be a good choice for back-ups (just remember that [it has to be fsck'ed](https://serverfault.com/questions/121268/jfs-or-xfs-or-anything-else/225082#225082) on unclean shutdown).

Answer (score 0):

I use btrfs. Why do I use something that isn't production quality? Because I've got several different backups, so corruption in one isn't a very big problem for me. And btrfs does checksums of data, so if I can recover from the backup, I can be sure that the data is intact.

Comment: Btrfs is still unstable. Mike wants a filesystem for backup, which means archival, perhaps for a long time (who knows when that data will be necessary?). I wouldn't recommend a filesystem that is not considered stable yet.

Comment: @Juliano: And you think I failed to bring this up in my answer?

Comment: I think he meant what happens if 5 years later you go back to the data only to find the specification was finalised after you wrote it and you cant read it back any more ?